# Limit vs interior definition of continuity

Tags: general-topology, analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Suppose I have two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ whose topologies are defined by interior operators $\text{int}_X$ and $\text{int}_Y$ respectively, as well as a function $f$ with domain $I$ (for input) and codomain $O$ (for output).

Here's where I hit my quandary: I see two potential routes for defining continuity. I could say the function $f: I \rightarrow O$ is **continuous at the point** $\tilde{x}$ iff $\lim_{x \rightarrow \tilde{x}} f(x) = f(\tilde{x})$, then say it's **continuous everywhere** in $I$ if it's continuous at every point $\tilde{x}$ in $I$.

Or, I could say the function $f: I \rightarrow O$ is **continuous** iff $f^{1-}\left[\text{int}_X(A)\right]$ is a subset of $\text{int}_Y \left( f^{1-}[A] \right)$ for any $A \subseteq O$. My question is: are these two definitions equivalent? Could someone give me some insight into their equivalence or lack thereof? (I'm assuming the limits are defined with respect to the topologies of $\text{int}_X$ and $\text{int}_Y$.)

Comment: How do you define a limit?

Comment: The **limit** of $f: I \rightarrow O$ near $\tilde{x} \in \text{int}_X(I)$ is $\tilde{y} \in O$ iff for any neighbourhood $V$ of $\tilde{y}$ there is a punctured neighbourhood $U$ of $\tilde{x}$ (i.e. a neighbourhood of $\tilde{x}$ with $\tilde{x}$ deleted) such that $f[U] \subseteq V$.

Answer (score -1):

Following article is giving the proof you're looking for: [Continuous functions and convergent sequences](http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/jabuka/Classes/2009_spring/topology/Notes/03%20-%20Continuous%20functions.pdf)

Comment: Whilst the information at this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: My question is an exercise at the end of the article :(